# How do I update a gem to a specific version on the command line?

Tags: command-line, rspec, rubygems, bundler

I'm using Rails 4.2.3.  I would like to update a specific gem (rspec) on the command line, however I can't seem to get it to work.

```
$ bundle update rspec-rails -version 3.9
No value provided for option '--retry'
$ bundle update rspec-rails -version 3.9 --retry==1
No value provided for option '--retry'
$ bundle update rspec-rails -version 3.9 --retry=1
No value provided for option '--retry'
```

What's the right way to update a gem to a specific version using the bin/bundle command line tool?

Answer (score 10):

The correct way to update the version of a gem to a specific version is to specify the version you want in your Gemfile, then run `bundle install`.

You can lock your bundle to a specific version, like this:

```
gem "rspec-rails", "3.9"
```

Or, you can do this to grab version 3.9 and all patches as they are released:

```
gem "rspec-rails", "~>3.9"
```

As for why your command line was failing, there is no `-version` option. And, because you used a single dash (`-`) the word `version` was interpreted as a list of one letter options, `-v`, `-e`, `-r`, etc. Since there are no `-v` or `-e` options, `bundler` ignored them and tried to use the `-r` option which is the short option for `--retry`. But, that option requires a parameter.

You can learn more about what options are available with this command:

```
bundle update --help
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it *only* from the command line, one way I found is to remove the gem and then re-add it at a specific version:

```bash
# first remove from the Gemfile and Gemfile.lock
bundle remove cocoapods

# now re-add it at the specific version we want
bundle add cocoapods --version 1.12.0
```

NB: this won't work perfectly in all situations but is good enough for me, for now.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to update the version like

from up version

```
gem 'ar-octopus'
```

to lower version

```
gem 'ar-octopus', '0.9.2'
```

Then run command

```
bundle update 'ar-octopus'
```

Gemfile.lock file shows the down version of the gem